# Why do we still need virtual memory in 21st century?

Tags: virtual-memory

AFAIU, there are only two issues, that VM solves:

1. Scarcity of RAM;
2. Access control to "unknown" memory, where SW tries to read from or write to the memory it does not own or share with other processes.

While p.1) is becoming a non-factor for more use-cases, than it probably was in the past, are there any solutions for guarding against buggy/malicious SW without VM? Something that is not that involved as VM and more predictable (constant access time)? How can an embedded multi-core systems implement protection if there is no VM?

Answer (score 3):

A key benefit of virtual memory (besides simulation of more RAM than truly available) is that *every process* sees the *whole address space* available to itself. This greatly simplifies memory mapping for the applications. Together with processor time sharing, every process gets an own, private and huge computer.

Answer (score 2):

> How can an embedded multi-core systems implement protection if there is no VM?

ARM Cortex M0+ with an MPU, as found in RP2040 for example (embedded multi-core controller), uses a limited number (namely 8) of configurable memory regions. Start, size, and protection bits can be set per region, and regions can overlap (which region takes priority is also configurable). Note that Cortex M0+ does not have an unprivileged execution mode, so this memory protection does nothing against malicious software - but that's not much of a concern for a microcontroller. That limitation is not inherent to this type of memory protection though.

In general, this type of memory protection is efficient and predictable, but not scalable: the number of regions must be small, since the MPU has to hold all regions in internal configuration registers at the same time and compare the address of each memory access to all bounds to find the region it's in. In parallel, of course, since it's in hardware - but that still doesn't scale very well.

Another alternative is some form of segmentation, where an advanced segmentation technique (not just a bare offset as in 8086) can support process isolation. But segmented memory is annoying to write software for, and tends to suffer from external fragmentation. Individual memory access when viewed in isolation can be efficient and predictable, without TLB misses, but a similar problem is off-loaded to software (which has a harder time dealing with it): segment registers and their hidden state are comparable to a software-managed TLB, but worse.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot more use cases for virtual memory. On top of address space separation as Yves pointed out, there are a bunch of others, for example:

- Sharing memory between processes. This is much more common than you think, since it's how running multiple copies of an executable, or shared libraries, are often handled.
- Memory-mapping files, which is a *much* more performant way to handle file I/O than an read/write-style API.

That last one is extremely important in modern computing. A modern operating system maintains a cache of data from disk. A read/write API means copying data between the buffer cache and process memory, but memory-mapped files means you can just map the buffer cache directly with no copying. Programs like database servers benefit enormously from this, because as RAM gets larger, databases also get larger.

Also, if you never modify the file, any part of the file you're not using require "allocating" RAM or swap. Compilers benefit from this, because they can just memory-map source code files.

Virtual memory can also simplify programming by effectively eliminating external fragmentation. On a 64-bit machine, there is more address space than you will ever need. So if you need an array but don't know how big it will be, you can reserve gigabytes of address space but only allocate as much actual RAM as you find that you need within that space.

One final thing to consider is that "scarcity of RAM" became a *financial* consideration when people started moving their services, written in managed languages, onto cloud providers.

Managed languages like Java or Python typically give you less control over how much RAM you use than a systems language like C++ or Rust. Cloud providers often have a limited range of virtual machines that you can deploy onto, and the amount of RAM typically scales with the number of CPUs. If you don't need that many GPUs, but do need working storage, it can be worth it to pay for a smaller machine and use swap storage.